# $.isNumeric to allow commas

Tags: jquery

I need to allow users to enter numbers with commas also.

Right niw im using the isNumeric jquery validation but it does not allow commas.

```
For Ex: 1,200,000.50 is invalid.
```

How do i validate this?

Below is what i added for all my currency values.

```js
if ($.isNumeric( $("#phone_number").val() ) || ( !$("#phone_number").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Phone Number is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#hour_per_week").val() ) || ( !$("#hour_per_week").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Hour Per Week is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#annual_leave").val() ) || ( !$("#annual_leave").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Annual Leave is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#sick_leave").val() ) || ( !$("#sick_leave").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Sick Leave is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#long_services").val() ) || ( !$("#long_services").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Long Services is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#amount").val() ) || ( !$("#amount").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Amount is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#home_residence").val() ) || ( !$("#home_residence").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Home Residence is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#investment_property1").val() ) || ( !$("#investment_property1").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Investment Property1 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#investment_property2").val() ) || ( !$("#investment_property2").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Investment Property2 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#investment_property3").val() ) || ( !$("#investment_property3").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Investment Property3 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#investment_property4").val() ) || ( !$("#investment_property4").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Investment Property4 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#home_contents").val() ) || ( !$("#home_contents").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Home Contents is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#motor_vehicle1").val() ) || ( !$("#motor_vehicle1").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Motor Vehicle1 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#motor_vehicle2").val() ) || ( !$("#motor_vehicle2").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Motor Vehicle2 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#motor_vehicle3").val() ) || ( !$("#motor_vehicle3").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Motor Vehicle2 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#motor_vehicle4").val() ) || ( !$("#motor_vehicle4").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Motor Vehicle2 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#caravan").val() ) || ( !$("#caravan").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Caravan is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#marine_craft").val() ) || ( !$("#marine_craft").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Marine Craft is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#managed_funds").val() ) || ( !$("#managed_funds").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Managed Funds is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#cash_bank").val() ) || ( !$("#cash_bank").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Cash Bank is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#offset_account_balance").val() ) || ( !$("#offset_account_balance").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Offset Account Balance is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_1").val() ) || ( !$("#other_1").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 1 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_2").val() ) || ( !$("#other_2").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 2 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_3").val() ) || ( !$("#other_3").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 3 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_4").val() ) || ( !$("#other_4").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 4 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_5").val() ) || ( !$("#other_5").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 5 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_6").val() ) || ( !$("#other_6").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 6 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_7").val() ) || ( !$("#other_7").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 7 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_8").val() ) || ( !$("#other_8").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 8 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_9").val() ) || ( !$("#other_9").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 9 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_10").val() ) || ( !$("#other_10").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other 10 is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#company_profile").val() ) || ( !$("#company_profile").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Company Profit is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#base_salary").val() ) || ( !$("#base_salary").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Base Salary is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#superannuation").val() ) || ( !$("#superannuation").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Superannuation is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#bonus_pa").val() ) || ( !$("#bonus_pa").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Bonus Pa is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#allowances_pa").val() ) || ( !$("#allowances_pa").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Allowances Pa is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#annuity").val() ) || ( !$("#annuity").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Annuity is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#foregin_pension_income_pa").val() ) || ( !$("#foregin_pension_income_pa").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Foregin Pension Income Pa is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#child_maintenance").val() ) || ( !$("#child_maintenance").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Child Maintenance is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#current_centrelink").val() ) || ( !$("#current_centrelink").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Current Centrelink is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#other_tax").val() ) || ( !$("#other_tax").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Other Tax is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#non_other_tax").val() ) || ( !$("#non_other_tax").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Non Other Tax is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#expenses").val() ) || ( !$("#expenses").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Expenses is invalid'); return false; }
if ($.isNumeric( $("#dividends").val() ) || ( !$("#dividends").val() ) ) {} else { alert('Dividends is invalid'); return false; }
```

Comment: `$("#phone_number").val().replace(/,/g, "")`?

Comment: You really should look at a validation plugin, or even writing your own to loop, eg `$(".must_be_numeric").each((i, e) => if (!$.isNumeric($(e).val()) alert($(e).data("validation-message"))` as a starter

Comment: You might consider using the [`pattern` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) instead of writing all this code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, i never thought that it can work that way. 

Im actually using jquery.validate(), and its working, but i don't know how to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: You should consider asking a question: *[tag:jquery-validate] how to stop form from submitting*  (though there's probably a couple already on SO)

Comment: Why do you have empty if blocks?

Comment: @biberman its because if one of the condition is true, i dont want any thing to happen.